# DataContractSerializer will not serialize protected properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I changed a public property of a class to protected

```
public class SlideSet : UserModifiable.Properties, Validation.IValidateable
{
    public virtual ICollection<Slide> Slides { get; set; }
```

to

```
public class SlideSet : UserModifiable.Properties, Validation.IValidateable
{
    [DataMember]
    protected virtual ICollection<Slide> Slides { get; set; }
```

but now DataContractSerializer no longer serializes it to xml. My impression [from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was that the `DataMember` attribute was the only thing necessary for this to work.

This is my serialization implementation

```
    public string ToXml(Object obj) {
        // set up DataContractSerializer to use the .NET ProxyDataContractResolver, which helps us to serialize EF objects
        var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(obj.GetType());
        var knownTypes = ObjectContext.GetKnownProxyTypes();
        var resolver = new ProxyDataContractResolver();
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(entityType, entityType.Name, string.Empty, knownTypes, 1000, true, true, null, resolver);

        // serialize to XML string
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
```

Why is my protected property not getting serialized?

Comment: @JustinNiessner No, how is that supposed to be used? This all works fine as long as things are public

Comment: @JustinNiessner that does work, thanks. Though the xml now is a distinctly different format for some reason

Comment: I switched my comment to an answer and will delete the other comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your XML properly serialized with the `DataContractSerializer`, you'll not only need to use `DataMemberAttribute` on each serialized property, but also `DataContractAttribute` on the class itself.

The two work hand in hand as described in the documentation:

[MSDN - DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks, any idea why my generated xml looks different? (find for my purposes, just weird)